# Call to undefined method CI_Encrypt::sha1()

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, codeigniter-2

I follow a tutorial from youtube [Tutorial codeigniter - Insert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4DGhtq6dso) but,
Im getting this error inside my controller file for my browser when im using the encryption library from codeigniter 2. 

Error code when using encryption.

```
$paramUsu['clave'] = $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('txtClave'));
```

But when im just passing it without the encryption it working just fine.

```
$paramUsu['clave'] = $this->input->post('txtClave');
```

Im getting this error at my browser:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Encrypt::sha1() in C:\xampp\htdocs\TRAINING\tutorialCI\application\controllers\cpersona.php on line 31
>   
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Error
>   
> Message: Call to undefined method CI_Encrypt::sha1()
>   
> Filename: controllers/cpersona.php
>   
> Line Number: 31
>   
> Backtrace:

Here is the code for my controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cpersona extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
                //call model
                $this->load->model('mpersona');
                $this->load->model('musuario');
                //call encryption library for password at 'clave' textfield
                $this->load->library('encrypt');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('persona/vpersona');
    }

    public function guardar(){
        //persona
        $param['dni'] = $this->input->post('txtDNI');
        $param['nombre'] = $this->input->post('txtNombre');
        $param['appaterno'] = $this->input->post('txtApPaterno');
        $param['apmaterno'] = $this->input->post('txtApMaterno');
        $param['email'] = $this->input->post('txtEmail');
        $param['fecnac'] = $this->input->post('datFecNac');
        //usuario
        $paramUsu['nomUsuario'] = $this->input->post('txtUsuario');
        //$paramUsu['clave'] = $this->input->post('txtClave');
        $paramUsu['clave'] = $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('txtClave'));

        //call function name in model
        //call function variable '$param'
        //$this->mpersona->guardar($param);

        $lastId = $this->mpersona->guardar($param);

        //check if $lastId is filled in persona table
        if ($lastId > 0){
            $paramUsu['idPersona'] = $lastId;
            //$paramUsu value will be go also in usuario model
            $this->musuario->guardarUsuario($paramUsu);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that you are not using CI 2.x as sha1 was removed at some stage in CI 3.x as both MD5 and SHA1 are no longer recommended.

Comment: I hope this guys tutorial shows you how to use form validation as the above example is also "not recommended" when it comes to handling forms. Plus it appears he has just thrown in the encrypt for fun... but then I do not understand what he is saying.

Comment: im using CI 2.2.6, im just getting familiar myself with this framework so that is why im following this tutorial to explore myself with CI. But if that the case is there a way for me to encrypt my password from this controller file? Thank you.

Comment: the language is in Spanish. Im neither not understand what he is saying.

Comment: ok well I've just pulled up CI 2.2.6 and it's there... So not sure why you cannot call it. if you insist on using this tutorial you can just replace it with the direct php sha1() function or just don't use it. Anyway I'd be looking up other tutorials that use CI 3

Comment: alright, thanx Tim. I guess im going to pass on this tutorial and continue on for the next video. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

its done 
I just do it like this.

$param['clave'] = sha1($this->input->post('txtClave'));

Comment: SHA1 was removed for a reason. It's a weak hash that's been compromised and is no longer useful from a security perspective. If this is for passwords, you **must** use a password-specific hashing method like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), which in PHP is done with the [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sha1 ()` as shown below:

```
$param['clave'] = sha1($this->input->post('txtClave'));
```

Comment: SHA1 is no longer useful from a security perspective, it should not be used for things like this.